# 'Freezing' an expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c-preprocessor

I have a C++ expression that I wish to 'freeze'. By this, I mean I have syntax like the following:

```
take x*x with x in container ...
```

where the `...` indicates further (non-useful to this problem) syntax. However, if I attempt to compile this, no matter what preprocessor translations I've used to make 'take' an 'operator' (in inverted commas because it's technically not an operator, but the translation phase turns it into a class with, say, operator* available to it), the compiler still attempts to evaluate / work out where the x*x is coming from, (and, since it hasn't been declared previously (as it's declared further at the 'in' stage), it instead) can't find it and throws a compile error.

My current idea essentially involves attempting to place the expression inside a lambda (and since we can deduce the type of the container, we can declare `x` with the right type as, say, `[](decltype(*begin(container)) x) { return x*x }` -- thus, when the compiler looks at this statement, it's valid and no error is thrown), however, I'm running into errors actually achieving this.

Thus, my question is:
Is there a way / what's the best way to 'freeze' the `x*x` part of my expression?

**EDIT**:
In an attempt to clarify my question, take the following. Assume that the operator- is defined in a sane way so that the following attempts to achieve what the above `take ...` syntax does:

`MyTakeClass() - x*x - MyWithClass() - x - MyInClass() - container ...`

When this statement is compiled, the compiler will throw an error; x is not declared so x*x makes no sense (nor does x - MyInClass(), etc, etc). What I'm trying to achieve is to find a way to make the above expression compile, using any voodoo magic available, *without* knowing the type of x (or, in fact, that it will be named x; it could viably be named 'somestupidvariablename') in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get the return type working? I'm not 100% sure what's being asked. If you are, [this](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#suffix-return) might help.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to compile!
As it stands, I've done something like `#define take Take_class() * `, and then defined operator* within Take_class(). However, when the preprocessor has finished its work, the expression will end up like:
`Take_class() * x*x == With_class() == x ...` (where I've just chosen the operators at random here; don't take them at anything other than face value). However, after this step, when attempting to compile the code, any compiler will then complain that `x` hasn't been declared.
It's the not-declared issue I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're trying to use the parameter type in the return type. When putting in the return type, the parameters haven't been declared yet. This was the cause for the suffix return type syntax, explained in the link I gave in my first comment.

Comment: Ah, right -- the issue is that I can't work out a way to turn the expression / syntax *into* the lambda; once i've done that I can deal with the delayed return syntax just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure that the C++ preprocessor is the best tool for developing a new language. In fact, I'm sure it isn't. What is the overall problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/libs/proto)? It is a library for building DSL embedded in C++, like what you're trying to do. I'm not sure the kind of DSL you're aiming for is actually possible in C++, though...

Comment: @Luc : Yeah, Haskell syntax in C++.. not likely.

Comment: You could pass `x*x` as an argument to your `take` macro. That would imply adding parentheses, though. Another solution is to use placeholders (see how it's done in [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.placeholders) for instance).

Comment: Yeah, it's highly possible that this isn't possible.
@CharlesBailey, it's my own small project; I figured something like this would be cool.

Comment: @LucTouraille: yeah, if i convert take / etc to functions, then it's possible to 'swap' the ordering of the syntax via the macros, and then it's easy enough to instantiate things in the right order -- though for now, I'm trying to find a way to avoid doing that.
Are you able to expand on your placeholder solution? (which may need to be taken to an answer....)

Comment: Try to clarify your question. Give a usage example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have the time to write up a complete answer on placeholders, especially since it is not the simplest thing to explain. However, [this article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1397) gives a good idea of how placeholders are implemented.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: added an edit that hopefully clarifies well enough?

Comment: since a container can only retrieve one element at a time, I still dont see the point of the 'with', which leaves me curious over where this syntax is coming from?  What are you doing?

Comment: Well, given the haskell-esque syntax, I figure it'll be possible to have something along the lines of `take x*y with x in container1 with y in container2', etc. etc. Basically, it's my own little project but ran into the predeclaration/brackets issue, so turned here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an answer very similar to my previous answer, but using *actual* expression templates, which should be *much faster*.  Unfortunately, MSVC10 crashes when it attempts to compile this, but MSVC11, GCC 4.7.0 and Clang 3.2 all compile and run it just fine.  (All other versions untested)

Here's the usage of the templates.  Implementation code is [here](http://ideone.com/ZR4kK).

```
#define take 
#define with ,
#define in >>= 

//function call for containers 
template<class lhsexpr, class container>
lhsexpr operator>>=(lhsexpr lhs, container& rhs)
{
    for(auto it=rhs.begin(); it!=rhs.end(); ++it)
        *it = lhs(*it);
    return lhs;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> container0;
    container0.push_back(-4);
    container0.push_back(0);
    container0.push_back(3);
    take x*x with x in container0; //here's the magic line
    for(auto it=container0.begin(); it!=container0.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto a = x+x*x+'a'*x;
    auto b = a; //make sure copies work
    b in container0;
    b in container1;
    std::cout << sizeof(b);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this is used exactly like my previous code, except now *all the functions are decided at compile time*, which means this will have exactly the same speed as a lambda.  In fact, C++11 lambdas were preceeded by [`boost::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/lambda.html) which works on *very* similar concepts.

This is a separate answer, because the code is *far* different, and *far* more complicated/intimidating.  That's also why the implementation is not in the answer itself.

Comment: Well, it seems that it's not entirely possible to do this without either predeclaration or without brackets. Shame, I guess. Thanks for all your help -- I'll mark this as the correct answer as it's by far the most in-depth.

Comment: @Ben Stott: it wasnt until I posted this answer that I'd realized how similar to boost::lambda this was.  Prefer boost to what I wrote.  And this is no more "proof" that the task is impossible than my first answer was, and I wouldnt be surprised if there was some magic way we all overlooked.

Comment: Yeah, as far as techniques go I'm not overly fussed; I hadn't actually heard of expression templates (though I've seen their use in things like dlib-ml and Eigen) but seeing them implemented is really awesome -- however, I have an idea on implementation anyway, so I'll try this idea along with boost::lambda and etc. in my implementation of this syntax, to see which works best.

There's probably some wizardry that has been overlooked, which is why I'm choosing to go with the `expression x;` way, for now, but I guess we'll find out. Thanks for all the effort!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an *almost* solution, based on expression templates (note: these are not expression templates, they are *based on* expression templates).  Unfortunately, I could not come up with a way that does not require you to predeclare `x`, but I *did* come up with a way to delay the type, so you only have to declare `x` one globally, and can use it for different types over and over in the same program/file/scope.  Here is the expression type that works the magic, which I designed to be very flexible, you should be able to easily add operations and uses at will.  It is used exactly how you described, except for the predeclaration of x.

Downsides I'm aware of: it does require `T*T`, `T+T`, and `T(long)` be compilable.

```
expression x(0, true); //x will be the 0th parameter.  Sorry: required :(

int main() {
    std::vector<int> container;
    container.push_back(-3);
    container.push_back(0);
    container.push_back(7);
    take x*x with x in container; //here's the magic line
    for(unsigned i=0; i<container.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << container[i] << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
    std::vector<float> container2;
    container2.push_back(-2.3);
    container2.push_back(0);
    container2.push_back(7.1);
    take 1+x with x in container2; //here's the magic line
    for(unsigned i=0; i<container2.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << container2[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

and here's the class and defines that makes it all work:

```
class expression {
    //addition and constants are unused, and merely shown for extendibility
    enum exprtype{parameter_type, constant_type, multiplication_type, addition_type} type;
    long long value; //for value types, and parameter number
    std::unique_ptr<expression> left; //for unary and binary functions
    std::unique_ptr<expression> right; //for binary functions
   
public:
    //constructors
    expression(long long val, bool is_variable=false) 
    :type(is_variable?parameter_type:constant_type), value(val)
    {}
    expression(const expression& rhs) 
    : type(rhs.type)
    , value(rhs.value)
    , left(rhs.left.get() ? std::unique_ptr<expression>(new expression(*rhs.left)) : std::unique_ptr<expression>(NULL))
    , right(rhs.right.get() ? std::unique_ptr<expression>(new expression(*rhs.right)) : std::unique_ptr<expression>(NULL))
    {}
    expression(expression&& rhs) 
    :type(rhs.type), value(rhs.value), left(std::move(rhs.left)), right(std::move(rhs.right)) 
    {}
    //assignment operator
    expression& operator=(expression rhs) {
       type = rhs.type;
       value = rhs.value;
       left = std::move(rhs.left);
       right = std::move(rhs.right);
       return *this;
    } 
 
    //operators
    friend expression operator*(expression lhs, expression rhs) {
        expression ret(0);
        ret.type = multiplication_type;
        ret.left = std::unique_ptr<expression>(new expression(std::move(lhs)));
        ret.right = std::unique_ptr<expression>(new expression(std::move(rhs)));
        return ret;
    }
    friend expression operator+(expression lhs, expression rhs) {
        expression ret(0);
        ret.type = addition_type;
        ret.left = std::unique_ptr<expression>(new expression(std::move(lhs)));
        ret.right = std::unique_ptr<expression>(new expression(std::move(rhs)));
        return ret;
    }
    
    //skip the parameter list, don't care.  Ignore it entirely
    expression& operator<<(const expression&) {return *this;}
    expression& operator,(const expression&) {return *this;}

    template<class container>    
    void operator>>(container& rhs) {
        for(auto it=rhs.begin(); it!=rhs.end(); ++it)
            *it = execute(*it);
    }  
private: 
    //execution
    template<class T>
    T execute(const T& p0) {
       switch(type) {
       case parameter_type :
           switch(value) {
           case 0: return p0; //only one variable
           default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid parameter ID");
           }
       case constant_type:
           return ((T)(value));
       case multiplication_type:
           return left->execute(p0) * right->execute(p0);
       case addition_type:
           return left->execute(p0) + right->execute(p0);
       default: 
           throw std::runtime_error("Invalid expression type");
       }
    }
    //This is also unused, and merely shown as extrapolation
    template<class T>
    T execute(const T& p0, const T& p1) {
       switch(type) {
       case parameter_type :
           switch(value) {
           case 0: return p0;
           case 1: return p1; //this version has two variables
           default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid parameter ID");
           }
       case constant_type:
           return value;
       case multiplication_type:
           return left->execute(p0, p1) * right->execute(p0, p1);
       case addition_type:
           return left->execute(p0, p1) + right->execute(p0, p1);
       default: 
           throw std::runtime_error("Invalid expression type");
       }
    }
}; 
#define take 
#define with <<
#define in >>
```

Compiles and runs with correct output at http://ideone.com/Dnb50

You may notice that since the `x` must be predeclared, the `with` section is ignored entirely.  There's almost no macro magic here, the macros effectively turn it into "`x*x >> x << container`", where the `>>x` does absolutely nothing at all.  So the expression is *effectively* "`x*x << container`".

Also note that this method is slow, because this is an *interpreter*, with almost all the slowdown that implies.  However, it has the bonus that it is *serializable*, you could save the function to a file, load it later, and execute it *then*.

[R.MartinhoFernandes](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4113354#4113354) has observed that the definition of `x` can be simplified to merely be `expression x;`, and it can deduce the order of parameters from the `with` section, but it would require a lot of rethinking of the design and would be more complicated.  I might come back and add that functionality later, but in the meantime, know that it is definitely possible.

---

If you can modify the expression to `take(x*x with x in container)`, than that would remove the need to predeclare `x`, with something far far simpler than expression templates.
   
    #define with ,
    #define in ,
    #define take(expr, var, con) \
       std::transform(con.begin(), con.end(), con.begin(), \
       [](const typename con::value_type& var) -> typename con::value_type \
       {return expr;});

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> container;
    container.push_back(-3);
    container.push_back(0);
    container.push_back(7);
    take(x*x with x in container); //here's the magic line
    for(unsigned i=0; i<container.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << container[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: It dawned on me eventually that actual expression templates would make this _much_ faster, if much more verbose.  I'll code that up later.  Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the extreme wizardry! I'd love to see your expression-template-based approach, though it seems either way I'll need x predeclared.....

Comment: @BenStott: is it really not an option to declare it as `expression x(0, true);`?  Notice that I then use it for `int` and `float` both.  And no, I can't think of rumor of a way in C++ to do it without declarations

Comment: Oh, sure - if there is absolutely no other way, then declaring the parameter name will have to be done beforehand. However, if that's the case, I'll also be able to modify the syntax slightly and thus 'with x in' won't be needed, etc.
For now, though, I'm mostly looking to see if anyone has any ideas r.e. *not* predeclaring variables.

Comment: @BenStott: wait, if you can modify the syntax at _all_, parenthesis would make this a _lot_ easier, and remove the need for predeclaration.  `take(x*x with x in container)`

Comment: Yeah, once I add parenthesis the problem becomes infinitely easier. If there's no way to go about this without predeclaration or parenthesis, then yeah, I guess I'll have to relent, but I'm still hoping someone somewhere might have some brilliant as-of-yet unthoughtof idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get this "list comprehesion" (not quite, but it is doing the same thing) ala haskell using the preprocessor. The preprocessor just does simple search and replace with the possibility of arguments, so it cannot perform arbitrary replacements. Especially changing the order of parts of expression is not possible.

I cannot see a way to do this, without changing the order, since you always need `x` somehow to appear before `x*x` to define this variable. Using a lambda will not help, since you still need `x` in front of the `x*x` part, even if it is just as an argument. This makes this syntax not possible.

There are some ways around this:

- Use a different preprocessor. There are preprocessors based on the ideas of Lisp-macros, which can be made syntax aware and hence can do arbitrary transformation of one syntax tree into another. One example is Camlp4/Camlp5 developed for the OCaml language. There are some very good tutorials on how to use this for arbitrary syntax transformation. I used to have an explanation on how to use Camlp4 to transform makefiles into C code, but I cannot find it anymore. There are some other tutorials on how to do such things.
- Change the syntax slightly. Such list comprehension is essientially just a syntactic simplification of the usage of a [Monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29). With the arrival of C++11 Monads have become possible in C++. However the syntactic sugar may not be. If you decide to wrap the stuff you are trying to do in a Monad, many things will still be possible, you will just have to change the syntax slightly. Implementing Monads in C++ is anything but fun though (although I first expected otherwise). Have a look [here](http://www.tcrueger.de/doku.php/blog/monads_for_c_0x) for some example how to get Monads in C++.

Comment: I'm not entirely sold that the preprocessor is the correct approach for this -- I simply don't know of any others and it feels like it's 'most possible' using the preprocessor for translation.
Though at this stage, changing the syntax seems to be the best option; changing them from object-style to function-style macros means I should be able to change the order of the macros and thus have things work properly -- this is what I'm aiming to avoid though; I prefer the syntax without `()` strewn everywhere...

Comment: @BenStott: This is also why I suggested, that you have a look at Monads. They will give you some more insights on what kind of syntax is around in other languages and maybe you'll find something you like better.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to parse it using the preprocessor.I do believe the preprocessor can be a very powerful tool for building EDSLs(embedded domain specific languages), but you must first understand the limitations of the preprocessor parsing things. The preprocessor can only parse out predefined tokens. So the syntax must be changed slightly by placing parenthesis around the expressions, and a `FREEZE` macro must surround it also(I just picked FREEZE, it could be called anything):

```
FREEZE(take(x*x) with(x, container))
```

Using this syntax you can convert it to a preprocessor sequence(using the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library, of course). Once you have it as a preprocessor sequence you can apply lots of algorithms to it to transform it to however you like. A similiar approach is done with the [Linq](http://pfultz2.github.com/Linq/) library for C++, where you can write this:

```
LINQ(from(x, numbers) where(x > 2) select(x * x))
```

Now, to convert to a pp sequence first you need to define the keywords to be parsed, like this:

```
#define KEYWORD(x) BOOST_PP_CAT(KEYWORD_, x)
#define KEYWORD_take (take)
#define KEYWORD_with (with)
```

So the way this will work is when you call `KEYWORD(take(x*x) with(x, container))` it will expand to `(take)(x*x) with(x, container)`, which is the first step towards converting it to a pp sequence. Now to keep going we need to use a while construct from the Boost.Preprocessor library, but first we need to define some little macros to help us along the way:

```
// Detects if the first token is parenthesis
#define IS_PAREN(x) IS_PAREN_CHECK(IS_PAREN_PROBE x)
#define IS_PAREN_CHECK(...) IS_PAREN_CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__,0)
#define IS_PAREN_PROBE(...) ~, 1,
#define IS_PAREN_CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
// Detect if the parameter is empty, works even if parenthesis are given
#define IS_EMPTY(x) BOOST_PP_CAT(IS_EMPTY_, IS_PAREN(x))(x)
#define IS_EMPTY_0(x) BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY(x)
#define IS_EMPTY_1(x) 0 

// Retrieves the first element of the sequence
// Example:
// HEAD((1)(2)(3)) // Expands to (1)
#define HEAD(x) PICK_HEAD(MARK x)
#define MARK(...) (__VA_ARGS__),
#define PICK_HEAD(...) PICK_HEAD_I(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define PICK_HEAD_I(x, ...) x

// Retrieves the tail of the sequence
// Example:
// TAIL((1)(2)(3)) // Expands to (2)(3)
#define TAIL(x) EAT x
#define EAT(...)
```

This provides some better detection of parenthesis and emptiness. And it provides a `HEAD` and `TAIL` macro which works slightly different than `BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD`. (Boost.Preprocessor can't handle sequences that have vardiac parameters). Now heres how we can define a `TO_SEQ` macro which uses the while construct:

```
#define TO_SEQ(x) TO_SEQ_WHILE_M \
( \
BOOST_PP_WHILE(TO_SEQ_WHILE_P, TO_SEQ_WHILE_O, (,x)) \
)

#define TO_SEQ_WHILE_P(r, state) TO_SEQ_P state
#define TO_SEQ_WHILE_O(r, state) TO_SEQ_O state
#define TO_SEQ_WHILE_M(state) TO_SEQ_M state

#define TO_SEQ_P(prev, tail) BOOST_PP_NOT(IS_EMPTY(tail))
#define TO_SEQ_O(prev, tail) \
BOOST_PP_IF(IS_PAREN(tail), \
TO_SEQ_PAREN, \
TO_SEQ_KEYWORD \
)(prev, tail)
#define TO_SEQ_PAREN(prev, tail) \
(prev (HEAD(tail)), TAIL(tail))

#define TO_SEQ_KEYWORD(prev, tail) \
TO_SEQ_REPLACE(prev, KEYWORD(tail))

#define TO_SEQ_REPLACE(prev, tail) \
(prev HEAD(tail), TAIL(tail))

#define TO_SEQ_M(prev, tail) prev
```

Now when you call `TO_SEQ(take(x*x) with(x, container))` you should get a sequence `(take)((x*x))(with)((x, container))`.

Now, this sequence is much easier to work with(because of the Boost.Preprocessor library). You can now reverse it, transform it, filter it, fold over it, etc. This is extremely powerful, and is much more flexible than having them defined as macros. For example, in the Linq library the query `from(x, numbers) where(x > 2) select(x * x)` gets transformed into these macros:

```
LINQ_WHERE(x, numbers)(x > 2) LINQ_SELECT(x, numbers)(x * x)
```

Which these macros, it will then generate the lambda for list comprehension, but they have much more to work with when it generates the lambda. The same can be done in your library too, `take(x*x) with(x, container)` could be transformed into something like this:

```
FREEZE_TAKE(x, container, x*x)
```

Plus, you aren't defining macros like `take` which invade the global space.

Note: These macros here require a C99 preprocessor and thus won't work in MSVC.(There are workarounds though)

Comment: Right, but the problem becomes a whole lot simpler if I have parenthesis -- it's a lot simpler to re-order the expression and I won't run into the same issue with the compiler attempting to compile x*x because of this.

I'm mostly trying to see if anyone has any ideas to avoid this. Thanks for the help though!