# Expression Template - Failed to specialize function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, expression-trees

I was attempting to make some expression templates as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009233/freezing-an-expression/11022554#11022554), but I'm getting compiler errors, that I can't figure out.  I have gotten the SSCCE quite small by now

```
template<class sub_expr>
class inherit2 : private sub_expr { //line 3
public:
    inherit2(sub_expr rhs) : sub_expr(rhs) {}
    template<class T>
    auto operator()(const T& v) const ->decltype(sub_expr::operator()(v)) //line 7
    {return sub_expr::operator()(v);}
};

class expression_parameter {
public:
    template<class T>
    const T& operator()(const T& v) const {return v;}
};

int main() {
    expression_parameter x;
    auto expr0 = x;
    int res0 = expr0(3); //line 20
    auto expr1 = inherit2<expression_parameter>(x); //line 21
    int res1 = expr1(3); //line 22
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with MSVC10++ I get this error:

```
f:\code\utilities\exprtemplate\exprtemplate\sscce.cpp(22): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type' inherit2<sub_expr>::operator ()(const T &) const'
with
[
    sub_expr=expression_parameter
]
With the following template arguments:
'int'
```

When I compile with GCC 4.6.3:

```
sscce.cpp: In instantiation of 'inherit2<expression_parameter>':
sscce.cpp:21:47:   instantiated from here
sscce.cpp:3:7: warning: base class 'class expression_parameter' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]
sscce.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sscce.cpp:22:20: error: no match for call to '(inherit2<expression_parameter>) (int)'
sscce.cpp:3:7: note: candidate is:
sscce.cpp:7:10: note: template<class T> decltype (sub_expr:: operator()(v)) inherit2::operator()(const T&) const [with T = T, sub_expr = expression_parameter, decltype (sub_expr:: operator()(v)) = decltype (expression_parameter::operator()(v))]
sscce.cpp:20:6: warning: unused variable 'res0' [-Wunused-variable]
sscce.cpp:22:6: warning: unused variable 'res1' [-Wunused-variable]
```

And finally Clang 3.1

```
sscce.cpp(22,12) :  error: no matching function for call to object of type 'inherit2<expression_parameter>'
        int res1 = expr1(3);
                   ^~~~~
sscce.cpp(7,9) :  note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int]
    auto operator()(const T& v) const ->decltype(sub_expr::operator()(v))
         ^
```

So in summary: it *appears* that I got the `decltype` wrong, but I can't figure out the correct way.  Can anyone help me figure out what is causing these errors?

Comment: Wild guess: Did you try `decltype( lhs()( v ) * rhs()( v ) )`?

Comment: Mr. Duck, you know better... ["*Please tag questions about C++11 with the C++ tag, along with the C++11 tag.*"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info) ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I wasn't aware of that, though in hindsight it makes perfect sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @dirkgently: A good thought, but seems to have no effect.  And when I tried `lhs(v)` the compilers assumed it was a construction.

Comment: @dirkgently: once I put in Luc's fix for the ambiguous base problem, _then_ your comment fixes my problem.  Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Done. Interesting bit of code. Can you post the simplified bit too?

Comment: @dirkgently: you mean the simplified code I put in the question an hour ago?  Look at my edit named "deleted 2451 characters in body"

Comment: @MooingDuck: Sorry, connectivity + cache issues. I'm not even sure this will get posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the errors I got from GCC suggested to me that there was an ambiguous base involved. Namely, `expression_multiply<expression_parameter, expression_parameter>` has `expression_parameter` as a (direct) base, and `inherit_again<expression_parameter>` which itself has `expression_parameter` as a base. This means that `lhs::operator()` is ambiguous in the scope of `expression_multiply<expression_parameter, expression_parameter>` (where `lhs` is in fact `expression_parameter`.

A further fix was needed in that `this` was needed in the return type of `operator()`, resulting in the following fixes:

```
// Instead of inherit_again
template<int N, class sub_expr>
class base : public sub_expr {
public:
    base(sub_expr rhs): sub_expr(std::move(rhs)) {}
};

template<class lhs_given, class rhs_given>
class expression_multiply: private base<0, lhs_given>, private base<1, rhs_given> {
    typedef base<0, lhs_given> lhs;
    typedef base<1, rhs_given> rhs;
public:
    expression_multiply(lhs_given l, rhs_given r):lhs(std::move(l)), rhs(std::move(r)) {}
    template<class T>
    auto operator()(const T& v) const
    -> decltype(this->lhs::operator()(v) * this->rhs::operator()(v))
    {
        return lhs::operator()(v) * rhs::operator()(v);
    }
};
```

No idea if the compiler is behaving correcting regarding the need for those two 'fixes'.

Comment: Does this compile on your machine?  Because on my machine I get "`error: invalid use of 'this' at top level`".  The index for the `base` type is a good idea though, thanks for that.

Comment: I rearranged a few things and figured out how to greatly simplify my SSCCE.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is compilable, yes. I don't recall if `this` is allowed to appear there, but in any case you can substitute it by `std::declval<expression_multiply const&>()`, or change the whole call to e.g. `std::declval<lhs const&>()(v)` or `std::declval<lhs const&>().operator()(v)`.

Comment: I tested this, it compiles in GCC and Clang, though MSVC bombs it.  dirkgently has a workaround that works in all 3, but I'll mark yours as the best answer, because (A) it's more than one sentence, and (2) you figured out the issue, and solved it with at least one compmiler.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addendum to Luc's fix. Use:

```
decltype(std::declval<lhs>()( v ) * std::declval<rhs>()( v ) )
```

To help the compiler deduce the type without much ado.